# Using SQS with related data (Haystack)

Tags: indexing, many-to-many, django-haystack

I having two fields for a Paragraph Model, with one of them being a ManyToMany field.

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.tag
admin.site.register(Tag)

class Paragraph(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article)
    text = models.TextField()
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "Headline: " + self.article.headline + " Tags: " +  ', '.join([t.tag for t in self.tags.all()])
admin.site.register(Paragraph)
```

And my .txt files reflects the ManyToMany relationship to index tags-

```
{{object.text}}
{% for tag in object.tags.all %}
{{tag.tag}}
{% endfor %}
```

My views.py then uses SQS to search for all the tags (I want to accomplish this first before including text field) and retrieves those. So in this case, the query is "Politics"-

```
def politics(request):
    paragraphs = []
    sqs = SearchQuerySet().filter(tag="Politics")
    paragraphs = [a.object for a in sqs[0:10]]
    return render_to_response("search/home_politics.html",{"paragraphs":paragraphs},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Edited:
and my search_indexes.py

```
class ParagraphIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text= indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    tags= indexes.CharField(model_attr='tags')
    def get_model(self):
        return Paragraph
    def index_queryset(self):
        return self.get_model().objects
    def load_all_queryset(self):
        # Pull all objects related to the Paragraph in search results.                                                                                                                    
        return Paragraph.objects.all().select_related()
```

However this doesn't retrive anything even though a few paragraphs have tags that are "Politics". Am I missing anything here or should I approach related data another way? I am a beginner with Haystack so any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this is a very [useful article](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/django-haystack/7EfL3obVIx0/2bT0Y-D1OcEJ) that helped me solve the problem.

Based on the article, this is how my search_indexes.py looks now:

```
class ParagraphIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    tags = indexes.MultiValueField()

    def prepare_tags(self,object):
        return [tag.tag for tag in object.tags.all()]

    def get_model(self):
        return Paragraph

    def index_queryset(self):
        return self.get_model().objects

    def load_all_queryset(self):
        # Pull all objects related to Paragraph in search results.                                                                                  
        return Paragraph.objects.all().select_related()
```

and my views.py:

```
def politics(request):
    paragraphs = []
    sqs = SearchQuerySet().filter(tags='Politics')
    paragraphs = [a.object for a in sqs[0:10]]
    return render_to_response("search/home.html",
            {"paragraphs":paragraphs},
            context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And I am using elasticsearch for the engine. Hope this helps!